# Rails migrations & PostgreSQL: separate user for migration and setting privileges for production user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, privileges, rails-migrations

I have two users in postgresql one of which is called `migration` and is used when Rails runs migrations on the production server. This user owns the production database. I also have `production` user who is supposed to have only the following privileges: `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` on the production database.

Problem is, every time a new table is created, I have to manually run this in psql:

```sql
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO production;

-- next line is needed for each new table which has an auto incrementing field, in this case - table `users`
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCE users_id_seq TO production;
```

because permissions for `production` user on newly created tables are not set automatically. What's the best way to do it automatically when running migrations? Any script available for Rails/Capistrano?

Comment: Did default privileges work for you? I'm having a very similar issue, except it has to do with my backup software. Every time a new table is created, backup user can't read it... yet I AM using default privs, seen clearly from \ddp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Postgres' `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to have it [automatically assign the rights](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) to *production* for all newly created tables.

Alternatively, you could write a custom Capistrano task to set the permissions that is called through the `after "deploy:migrate", "mycustomtaskname"` hook. [This pastie](http://pastebin.com/vCtEqPi9) might give you a few good hints on how to interact with pgsql through Capistrano, for example how to provide the password interactively.

Comment: Thanks, looks like `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILIGES` is something that would save me from writing a custom Capistrano task and would replace very well both GRANT statements in my question. I will mark the answer correct as soon as I test how good the first solution works.